# create a new object Id in mongoDB using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am using the below code to insert data to mongodb

```
    router.post('/NewStory', function (req, res) {
var currentObject = { user: userId , story : story , _id:new ObjectID().toHexString() };
        req.db.get('clnTemple').findAndModify({
            query: { _id: req.body.postId },
            update: { $addToSet: { Stories: currentObject } },
            upsert: true
        });
});
```

This code is working fine if i remove the `_id:new ObjectID().toHexString()`

What i want to achieve here is that for every new story i want a unique **_id** object to be attached to it

What am i doing wrong?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55ae24016fb73f6ac7c2d640"
    },
    "Name": "some name",
     ...... some other details
    "Stories": [
        {
            "userId": "105304831528398207103",
            "story": "some story"
        },
        {
            "userId": "105304831528398207103",
            "story": "some story"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the document model, the _id that i am trying to create is for the stories

Comment: you dont need to do this mongodb automatically create _id property as a uniqe id

Comment: where is this ObjectID initialized

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not be calling `.toHexString()` on this as you would be getting a "string" and not an ObjectID. A string takes more space than the bytes of an `ObjectId`.

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    db = require('monk')('localhost/test'),
    ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;


var coll = db.get('junk');

var obj = { "_id": new ObjectID(), "name": "Bill" };

coll.findAndModify(
  { "_id": new ObjectID() },
  { "$addToSet": { "stories": obj } },
  {
    "upsert": true,
    "new": true
  },
  function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(doc);
  }
)
```

So that works perfectly for me. Noting the "new" option there as well so the modified document is returned, rather than the original form of the document which is the default.

```js
 { _id: 55c04b5b52d0ec940694f819,
   stories: [ { _id: 55c04b5b52d0ec940694f818, name: 'Bill' } ] }
```

There is however a catch here, and that is that if you are using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) and generating a new `ObjectId` for every item, then that new `ObjectId` makes everything "unique". So you would keep adding things into the "set". This may as well be [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) if that is what you want to do.

So if `userId` and `story` in combination already make this "unique", then do this way instead:

```js
coll.findAndModify(
  { 
      "_id": docId, 
      "stories": {
          "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "userId": userId, "story": story } }
      }
  },
  { "$push": { 
     "stories": {
         "userId": userId, "story": story, "_id": new ObjectID()
     }
  }},
  {
    "new": true
  },
  function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(doc);
  }
)
```

So test for the presence of the unique elements in the array, and where they do not exist then append them to the array. Also noting there that you cannot do an "inequality match" on the array element while mixing with "upserts". Your test to "upsert" the document should be on the primary "_id" value only. Managing array entries and document "upserts" need to be in separate update operations. Do not try an mix the two, otherwise you will end up creating new documents when you did not intend to.

Comment: thanks
I used the same code and it worked
removed the async alone
will it have any major impact

Comment: user id and story will not be making a unique key in my scenario as one user might add multiple stories

Comment: @vignesh This is why I say "IF" that is the case. The thing to need to be aware of though is that by creating a "new" ObjectId value every time, then you are nullifying the need for `$addToSet`. By definition each "new" item added to the array is always then "unique".

Comment: is there a bug in Stackoverflow? I remember seeing around 4K points for @Blakes Seven and it is showing just 1 now?!

Answer (score 3):

By the way, you can generate an `ObjectID` just using `monk`.

```
var db = monk(credentials.database);

var ObjectID = db.helper.id.ObjectID

console.log(ObjectID()) // generates an ObjectID
```